# Why SQL INSERT query takes the entered values as column names

Tags: mysql, mysql-insert-id, insert-query

I have a problem with the SQL INSERT QUERY. Whenever I execute the INSERT QUERY in the below code, what happens, is the query understands the values to be entered as the column names. My code is :

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db","root","123456");
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    int start = 8, end = 10;
    char buf[] = new char[end-start];   // for extracting day alone.

    dvalue = new String();
    ddvalue = new String(); // for adding the extracted day to the table.
    dvalue = cb3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    dvalue.getChars(start, end, buf, 0);System.out.println(buf);
    ddvalue = String.copyValueOf(buf);


    s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values (hello,"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
}
catch(SQLException s)
{
    System.out.println("SQL statemnet is not executed!");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The error that I get after executing the query is :-

SQL statemnet is not executed!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'hello' in 'field list'

-- EDIT--
Actually, my code was :

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+""+ddvalue+""+") values ("+cb5.getSelectedItem()+","+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
```

When I insert the quotes like everyone said, what happens is that the term "cb5.getSelectedItem()" is being entered into the table. The case with "+cb3.getSelectedItem()+" is that, it just enteres some garbage value.

Comment: Um, try quoting the string 'hello'?

Comment: give strings in single quotes giv me ur table name and column name

Comment: Actually, I don't know the names of columns. It depends on the input by the user. 
The only column name I know is sname. The other column name is obtained by the user input through the JComboBox object cb3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the string `hello` in your query.

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values ('hello',"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
```

Comment: Thanks man, that actually worked out like a charm. Actually, my code was 
s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values ("+cb5.getSelectedItem()+","+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");

When I insert the quotes like you specified, what happens is that the term "cb5.getSelectedItem()" is being entered into the table.
The case with "+cb3.getSelectedItem()+" is that, it just enteres some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with single quotes around hello -  e.g   'hello'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values ('hello',"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to add quotes to strings. Please, try doing this:

```
>     s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values
> ('hello','"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+"')");
```

**Note** I added the char `'` at the beginning and at the end of the string you are trying to insert.

Why SQL thinks your string was a column?
Imagine how the string you send to sql is:

```
"insert into OneTable (Field1, Field2) values (Hello, George)"
Instead of (the correct one):
```

> **"insert into OneTable (Field1, Field2) values ('Hello', 'George')"**

Comment: s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values ("+cb3.getSelectedItem()+","+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");

How to use quotes for this ?

Comment: Hi Roshan, you should do something like this: `s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+""+ddvalue+""+") values ('"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+"','"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+"')");` Assuming both values are strings. I'd suggest to you String.Format in order to build this string in a clearer way. Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert quotation marks around `hello` , this is how mysql came to know that the value is integer or string,
use either `' '`

```
 s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values ('hello',"+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
```

or `\" \"` both do work

```
 s.executeUpdate("insert into "+nameoftab+" (sname,"+"_"+ddvalue+"_"+") values (\"hello\","+cb3.getSelectedItem()+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead, so as not to have to deal with such quoting issues -- and you get protection from SQL injection attacks as an added benefit.

Comment: Even when trying with PreparedStatement, it was generating the same issue. So, I reverted back.

Comment: I simply meant that when binding placeholders, the need for `CONCAT()` is usually plainly obvious; otherwise it's merely `?`, unobscured by string concatenation to form the statement itself.